# pandas read_sql is unusually slow

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm trying to read several columns from three different MySQL tables into three different dataframes.

It doesn't take long to read from the database, but actually putting them into a dataframe is fairly slow.

```
start_time = time.time()
print('Reading data from database...')

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
q_crash = 'SELECT <query string> FROM table1'
q_vehicle = 'SELECT <query string> table2'
q_person = 'SELECT <query string> FROM table3'
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@host:port/dbasename')

print('Database time: {:.1f}'.format(time.time() - start_time))

crash = pd.read_sql_query(q_crash, engine)
print('Read_sql time for table 1: {:.1f}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
vehicle = pd.read_sql_query(q_vehicle, engine)
print('Read_sql time for table 2: {:.1f}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
person = pd.read_sql_query(q_person, engine)
print('Read_sql time for table 3: {:.1f}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
Reading data from database...
Database time: 0.0
Read_sql time for table 1: 13.4
Read_sql time for table 2: 30.9
Read_sql time for table 3: 49.4
```

Is this normal? The tables are quite large-- table 3 is over 601,000 rows. But pandas has handled larger datasets without a hitch whenever I use read_csv.

Comment: Are you reading from tables or views?

Comment: How long do the queries take when you run them from the command line or from some tool like MySQL workbench (running on the same machine that your Python script is on)?

Comment: I have never created a view and don't know anything about them, so I assume I'm reading from a table. @scomes, when I run the same query from the command line it takes less than a second.

Comment: Can you specify what client you are using on the command line? Because if I do a select query from the `mysql` command line program it takes quite some time to print 600,000 rows. And if you do the select query in the MySQL workbench there is a default maximum of 2000 rows which is being retrieved.

Comment: OK. That makes more sense, because I am using the mysql command line program as well, but I made a mistake and accidentally included LIMIT = 20; on the end of the query (copy/pasting from an earlier query) so that's probably why it was so fast. When I removed the LIMIT statement it slowed down drastically.

Comment: This sounds like an SQL problem and not Python as you probably need to optimize your query. Maybe you are running complex correlated subqueries or are not indexing tables optimally? Consider posting query and maybe table schema for more help.

Answer (score 4):

`pandas.read_sql` can be slow when loading large result set. In this case you can give a try on our tool [ConnectorX](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x) (`pip install -U connectorx`). We provide the `read_sql` functionality and aim to improve the performance in both speed and memory usage.

In your example you can switch to it like this:

```
import connectorx as cx

start_time = time.time()

q_crash = 'SELECT <query string> FROM table1'
q_vehicle = 'SELECT <query string> table2'
q_person = 'SELECT <query string> FROM table3'
db_url = "mysql://user:password@host:port/dbasename"

crash = cx.read_sql(q_crash, db_url)
print('Read_sql time for table 1: {:.1f}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
vehicle = cx.read_sql(q_vehicle, db_url)
print('Read_sql time for table 2: {:.1f}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
person = cx.read_sql(q_person, db_url)
print('Read_sql time for table 3: {:.1f}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Furthermore, you can leverage multi-cores on your client machine by specifying a partition column (`partition_on`) and partition number (`partition_num`), in which `ConnectorX` would split the original query and fetch the result of each split in parallel. You can find some examples of how to do it [here](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x#examples).

This is our benchmark result using 4 threads on MySQL fetching 60M rows x 16 columns of data:

[image: mysql time]
[image: mysql memory]

Comment: Doesn't really work with Azure MS SQL.

Answer (score -1):

IMO it doesn't make much sense to read up complete tables to Pandas DFs if you have them in MySQL DB - why don't you use SQL for filtering and joining your data? Do you really need **all** rows from those three tables as Pandas DFs?

If you want to join them you could do it first on the MySQL side and load the result set into single DF...

something similar to:

```
qry = 'select p.*, v.*, c.* from vehicle v join person p on v.id = p.vehicle_id join crash c on c.id = p.crash_id where <additional where clause>'
df = pd.read_sql(qry, engine)
```

Comment: doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: I up voted this comment, but I feel bad about it. The answer may well be the right one, trying to be helpful on SO can be hard, many people use the tool they know over the right tool for the job and it can be hard to be helpful, "I asked for help on how to did a trench with a spoon, I didn't ask about using a 'tractor' or whatever that is."